# Can't connect to remote MySQL (MariaDB) database in .NET but I can with Java

Tags: java, c#, mysql, winforms, mariadb

I am trying to migrate some code from JavaFX to use C# for Windows Forms. In Java, I was using JDBC and could connect just fine programmatically. Nos that I am trying to use C# I am getting this error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).
```

I am using the same server address and credentials. I'm using System.Data.SqlClient. I've tried a bunch of different combinations but can't get the connection string to work.

```
String connectionString = "server=[Server URL];database=[Database Name];persist security info=true;user id=[Username];pwd=[Password]";
```

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` is for Microsoft SQL Server only. You will need to use `System.Data.Odbc` or the MySQL Connector at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the mysql connection string:

```
string connectionString = "datasource= <database ip or domain>; port=<port, usually 3306>;username=<database user>;password=<user's password>;SslMode=none<this is important if you don't use ssl>;database=<your database>";
```

I think the reason you can't connect is because you haven't specified the SslMode.